# Index an array with the rows of another array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

For example i have an array as

```
a=    [[[98, 92, 92, 81],
        [98, 26, 98, 36],
        [83, 39, 96, 73],
        [75, 36, 37, 68],
        [56, 87, 62, 73]],

       [[98, 43, 36, 96],
        [92, 88, 94, 71],
        [ 7, 24, 33, 18],
        [14, 75, 30, 43],
        [91, 54, 74, 59]],

       [[60, 97, 52, 95],
        [78, 90, 99, 16],
        [59, 89,  5, 85],
        [44, 33, 52, 93],
        [41, 77, 64, 88]]]
```

and indexing array as

```
b= [[1, 4],
    [1, 3],
    [0, 4]]
```

Then i want the final output as the output of the for loop as follows

```
for i in range(3):
        a[i, b[i]]
```

and sample output as

```
[[[98, 26, 98, 36],
  [56, 87, 62, 73]],
  
 [[14, 75, 30, 43],
  [92, 88, 94, 71]],

 [[41, 77, 64, 88],
  [60, 97, 52, 95]]]
```

I need this for applying batch indexing to batched data. So normally i would apply one row of index vector to one matrix(2D) in batched data

Comment: The bottom two frames have swapped rows in the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

For the case you show, maybe something like this would do:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array(a)
```

using your array of indices `b`, make the selection of the elements:

```py
parts  = [a[n,i,:] for n,i in enumerate(b)]
```

and at the end convert the parts list to one array:

```py
np.array(parts)
```

results:

```
array([[[98, 26, 98, 36],
        [56, 87, 62, 73]],
       [[92, 88, 94, 71],
        [14, 75, 30, 43]],
       [[60, 97, 52, 95],
        [41, 77, 64, 88]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with direct indexing. The output shape will be the broadcasted shape of of the input plus the axes with `:`:

```
a[np.arange(3).reshape(-1, 1), b, :]
```

You can also use `np.take_along_axis`:

```
np.take_along_axis(a, b[..., None], axis=1)
```